# Fail to send data to server using json

Tags: ajax, json

I am setting up new payment method in e-shop.
The requirements are:

    `URL: POST https://payparts2.privatbank.ua/ipp/v2/payment/create
    server-server
    Headers
    Accept: application/json;
    Accept-Encoding: UTF-8;
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8;
    Body
    {
    "storeId": "",
    "orderId": "",
    "amount": 300.00,
    "currency": "980",
    "partsCount": 6,
    "merchantType": "PP",
    "products": [
        {
            "name": "TV",
            "count": 2,
            "price": 100.00
        },
        {
            "name": "microwave",
            "count": 1,
            "price": 200.00
        }
    ],
    "responseUrl": "http://shop.com/response",
    "redirectUrl": "http://shop.com/redirect",
    "signature": ""

    }`

Here's my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/olga_smelo/hasb5kkr/9/
I've got an error:
*FAILContent type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supporteduk_UA*
, but I set "Content type" as "application/json" in ajax

Help me please!

Comment: try omitting  charset=UTF-8; in content type

Comment: Thank you for answer. But it doesn't help

Comment: AFAIK, `Accept-Encoding` should not be used for charsets, but for compression etc. See [this mozilla document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation#The_Accept-Encoding.3A_header).